# Ring homomorphism $f: \Bbb{Z}_p[X] \to \Bbb{Z}_p^{n\times n}$. Prove it is never bijective and find the amount of elements in Im$(f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, jordan-normal-form, jordan-algebras

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_p[X] \to \mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$
with $n \geq 2$ be a ring homomorphism with $f(1) = I_n, f(X) = M$.

a) Prove it is never injective and never surjective.

b) Find the minimal polynomial and the amount of elements $ \operatorname{Im}(f)$ with $p=3, n=6$ and with $M$ given:
$f(X)= M  = \left( \begin{matrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right).$

---

a) I first proved that $f$ is fully determined by $f(X)$.
$f(p(X)) = f(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX^i) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i)f(X^i) =  \sum_{i=1}^n a_if(X)^i$, so we see that indeed $f$ is determined by the value of $f(X)$. (These operations are allowed since $f$ is a ring homomorphism).

Then I tried proving that it is never injective.
Since $M \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$, I know that there exists a $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M^q = 0$ with $q$ a divisor of $p$.
Consider $p(X) = X^i$, then $f(p(X)) = p(f(X)) = p(0) = 0$, which means that $p(X) \in \text{ker}(f)$ and since the kernel is not equal to $\{0\}$ we know it is not injective.

I am not sure how to prove that it is never surjective.

b) I think that the minimal polynomial is equal to $\phi_M(X) = (X-2)^2(X-1)$ since there are 2 Jordan blocks for eigenvalue 2 and 1 for eigenvalue 1.

I don't really know how to calculate the amount of elements that $ \operatorname{Im}(f)$ has.

Comment: By $\mathbb Z_p$ I assume you mean the integers modulo $p$.  In that case, $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ is infinite while $\mathbb Z_p^{n^2}$ is finite, so $f$ can never be injective (your proof for (a) does not make sense).

Comment: To prove $f$ can't be surjective, use the isomorphism theorem $$\mathrm{Im}(f) \cong \Bbb Z_p[X] / \ker f$$ Since $\Bbb Z_p[X]$ is commutative, so is the image of $f$. However, the codomain is not commutative: it can't be equal to the image of $f$.

Comment: Your proof of injectivity **is** correct provided that $M$ is a non-zero nilpotent matrix, e.g. the one having $1$s above the main diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a): Your proof of injectivity is not correct. For example if $M$ is the identity matrix, then $M^k=I\ne0$ for all $k$. One way would be to argue via cardinalities: $\Bbb Z_p[X]$ is infinite while $\Bbb Z_p^{n\times n}$ is finite, so ....
A bit cleaner/more general argument would be to look at the dimension. $\Bbb Z_p^{n\times n}$ has dimension $n^2$, hence the set $\{I,M,\dots,M^{n^2}\}$ is linearly dependent, so there are coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_{n^2}$, not all equal to $0$, such that $$a_0I+\dots+a_{n^2}M^{n^2}=0$$ Now see how you can make a non-zero polynomial $p$ out of this such that $p(M)=0$.
Hint for the surjective part: $\Bbb Z_p[X]$ is commutative while $\Bbb Z_p^{n\times n}$ is not.
For b): For the minimal polynomial you need to look at the *size of the largest* Jordan block for each eigenvalue and not the *number* of Jordan blocks.
Assume that we found the minimal polynomial $\phi$ and say it is of degree $d$. We know that $\ker f=\langle\phi\rangle$, hence $$\operatorname{im} f\cong \Bbb Z_p[X]/\langle\phi\rangle$$
In general for a field $K$ and a polynomial $p$ over $K$ of degree $n$ we have that $K[X]/\langle p\rangle$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ (if you don't know this try to prove this, e.g. by explicitely writing down a basis). So in this case we know that $\operatorname{im} f$ is a $\Bbb Z_p$-vector space of dimension $d$. What does this tell us about the cardinality?

Comment: Thank you, I understand the injective part of the proof. For the surjective part: with the isomorphism theorem we know that $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/ker(f) \cong Im(f)$. Since    $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ is commutative and $ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup, this implies that $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/ker(f)$ is commutative which means that $Im(f) \subset \mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$ and can't be equal, otherwise $\mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$ would be commutative. (Does this also mean that $Im(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$.) For b) i think it tells us that the cardinality is $p^d$.

Comment: Yes, although I wouldn't call $\ker f$ a 'normal subgroup' (which is correct of course) but rather an 'ideal', because subgroup would sound like you look at the underlying additive groups - and these are abelian in all rings. And yes, $\operatorname{im} f$ has $p^d$ elements.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to double check, the minimal polynomial would then be $\phi = (X-2)^3(X-1)$ and then the cardinality would be $p^{3+1} = p^4$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

A ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]\to\mathbb{Z}_p^{n\times n}$ *can* be surjective, precisely when $n=1$. In this case, send a polynomial to its constant term.

For $n>1$ such a homomorphism cannot be surjective, because the domain is commutative and the codomain isn't.

So this generalizes to the case $A[X]\to A^{n\times n}$, where $A$ is *any* commutative ring.

Proving that such a homomorphism cannot be injective is the same as proving that for every $M\in A^{n\times n}$, there is a nonzero polynomial $a_0+a_1X+\dots+a^kX^k$ such that
$$
a_0I+a_1M+\dots+a_kM^k=0
$$
This is easier when $A$ is a field, because in this case the set $\{I,M,\dots,M^{n^2}\}$ has more elements than the dimension of $A^{n\times n}$ as $A$-vector space; a nontrivial linear combination will provide the required polynomial.

---

For general commutative rings one can observe that Hamilton-Cayley holds, but this requires proving it. If you know a proof for matrices over a field, then you can consider the field of fractions $F$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X_{ij}:1\le i,j\le n]$ (polynomials over $n^2$ indeterminates). Let $\xi$ be the matrix having $X_{ij}$ as its $(i,j)$ entry. Then the characteristic polynomial $p(X)$ of $\xi$ (where $X$ is another indeterminate) is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X_{ij},X]$ and we know that $p(\xi)=0$. Given a matrix $M=(m_{ij})\in A^{n\times n}$, consider the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X_{ij}]\to A^{n\times n}$ defined by $X_{ij}\mapsto m_{ij}$ and finish up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I understand the first part. The second part ("For general commutative ringes...": I don't quite understand why you have to prove Hamilton-Cayley holds since I know it holds for a field. Is it because $\mathbb{Z}_p^{n \times n}$ isn't a field, or has zero divisors? Or what are you trying to show with this second part?

Comment: @fieke_2000 If Hamilton-Cayley holds then any matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial. If $f\colon A[X]\to A^{n\times n}$ is a ring homomorphism, then $M=f(X)$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, which is then in the kernel of $f$.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you very much!